# two foreign keys on same table to display parent fields

Tags: sql, sqlite, t-sql

i have two tables
details like below

```
user master
----------------
userid int (pk)
username
useraddress

user transactions
-----------------
fromUser int (fk - userid)
toUser int (fk - userid)
amount
```

i need to display data as follows

```
fromUsername
toUsername
amount
```

i tried many queries but i am unable to form a proper select query

tried googling and much more but due to lack of searching with proper keyword i am unable to find the desired answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need two joins:

```
select mf.username, mt.username, t.amount
from transactions t join
     master mf
     on t.fromUser = mf.userId join
     master mt
     on t.toUser = mt.userId;
```

If either user could be `NULL` or invalid, use `left join` instead of `join`.